# Air Transit in Bucharest question

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, romania, bucharest

I have Schengen visa and I'm going from Amman to Budapest but I have a stop in Bucharest for two hours, can I enter the airport in Romania without their visa, or does the Schengen visa work?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a valid Schengen visa, you're allowed to transit Bucharest airport (even though it's not in Schengen) for max 24 hours on your way to Budapest.

Comment: Romania isn't part of Schengen, do you have a reference for your answer ?

Comment: @blackbird Firstly, most nationalities never require a visa simply for transiting a European Airport (and OP is only changing planes). Secondly, a Schengen visa is also valid for transiting Romania, Bulgaria, Croatia or Cyprus on your way to/from the Schengen area. If having a double or multiple-entry visa and having already entered Schengen, you can even visit These countries on your Schengen visa. All of this is stated in Timatic, the database by IATA which Airlines use